# Grid.reconfigure not working in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a reset button for my grid that is supposed to reset all my columns. Code looks like this :

```
               function (response) {
                    if (response == 'yes') {

                        Ext.state.Manager.clear(grid.stateId);

                        var cols = grid.initialConfig.columns

                        grid.reconfigure(grid.getStore(), cols);
                    }
                });
```

**grid.reconfigure(..)** is supposed to reset how the table looks, however nothing happens when I run the code above.

I noticed that **grid.initialConfig.columns** is undefined. Why would this be undefined? Is there some kind of initial configuration that needs to be set first?

(I notice that when using a constructor you can define an *initialConfiguration*. I used *initComponent* instead.)

Comment: if `grid.initialConfig.columns` is undefined, how can you expect `grid.reconfigure` to work?

Comment: yes you are right. I answered myself below by setting initialConfig.columns in my initComponent. Its just that i had never seen the code used that way before in any of the demos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my initComponent(..) for my grid I added **this.initialConfig.columns = this.columns**

> ```
> initComponent : function (){
>     var me = this;
>
>     this.columns = createColumns();
>
>     this.initialConfig.columns = this.columns;
> ```

This has fixed column issues :) But it doesn't reset sorting :(

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
initComponent : function (){
    var me = this;

    // we can expect that ExtJS wan't change a config 
    // but to be really sure we clone the array. 
    // (You may check this, because I think we don't even need this) 
    me.columnsCfg = me.columns.slice(0);

    ....
}
```

and the reconfigure

```
function (response) {
    if (response == 'yes') {
          // the grid state saves the ordering and visibility
          Ext.state.Manager.clear(grid.stateId);
          // the store saves the sorting (maybe the filtering to if it)
          Ext.state.Manager.clear(grid.getStore().stateId);
          grid.getStore().load(); // you may call reload if you want to resend the last load params

          grid.reconfigure(grid.getStore(), grid.columnsCfg);
     }
});
```

It looks a bit weird what you are doing with the columns. You should stay with simply configurations and not initialized columns. Note that while the grid get initialized it will override the columns reference with the initialized columns. The next point you miss is that not the grid saves the sorting, the store does. So you will need to reset the store to and reload it. I must admit that this is theory and that I don't tested it. In the the real world cases that I faced the store state was disabled.