# Extjs grid.reconfigure throws Exception (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSorter' of null)

Tags: extjs

I'm trying to reset grid to initial state before any user's changes of column width, order, visibility and so on. I saved columnConfigs in initialConfig of grid like that

```
var gridColumns = grid.getColumns();
        var initialColumnConfigs = [];
        Ext.Array.map(gridColumns, function (column) {
            initialColumnConfigs.push(column.getInitialConfig());
        });
        grid.getInitialConfig().initialColumnConfigs = initialColumnConfigs;
```

and now I'm trying to reset grid using reconfigure like that:

```
initialColumnConfigs = grid.getInitialConfig().initialColumnConfigs;
        Ext.state.Manager.clear(grid.stateId);
        grid.reconfigure(grid.getStore(), initialColumnConfigs);
```

but I end up with exception from title. Is there something that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is your Extjs version? Did you try `grid.reconfigure(grid.getStore(), grid.initialConfig.columns);` ?

Comment: 6.7. There is no "columns" attribute in grid's initial config

Comment: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/37ib I've found a sample and tried it in 6.7 and it has worked. Maybe this helps.

Comment: it looks nice, but there is grid.initialConfig.columns used there and as I said, this field is undefined in my case. I tried also this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452088/grid-reconfigure-not-working-in-extjs but I still get exception. In this case "cannot read property items of null"

Comment: Do you have any chance to create a Sencha Fiddle sample?